# mkdir() not chmodding the directory

Tags: php, linux, mkdir

I'm using the following code to create a directory...

```
mkdir($basedir.$plan_name, 0777, 1);
```

It creates, but the issue is that the 777 permissions aren't sticking

Any ideas?

My directory structure is this....

/pdf/customs (owned by wwwuser:user)
/pdf/customs/417/Folder Name (created by code, modded to 755)

Comment: `0777` is the default. The `mode` is ignored by Windows machines. Make sure your `umask` is set properly on a *nix machine.

Comment: @jnpcl Usually, a `umask` of `0022` is "set properly" and it's better to explicitly `chmod` then mess with it, **especially** if you're inside a web server.

Answer (score 4):

Your `umask` is probably `022`.  For more information, read `man 2 mkdir`.  You must use `chmod` after you make the directory to set the permissions to `0777`.

**Edit:** As others have suggested, you *can* change your umask instead.  However, if something goes wrong, the umask will stick around and your webserver or fastcgi daemon (or whatever) will start creating world-writable files and directories.  That's bad news.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your `umask` ?

The directory permissions will be modified by that.  For example if your umask value is `002` the resulting permissions will be `0775`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php):

> Note that you probably want to specify
>   the mode as an octal number, which
>   means it should have a leading zero.
>   *The mode is also modified by the
>   current umask, which you can change
>   using umask().*

What is your [umask](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php)?